# /proc/config.gz does not exist

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, adb

I have a Sony Xperia P. I have installed a custom kernel which I complied myself. Now I cant find its `config.gz`. It is not there in `/proc/config.gz`. Im not sure whether or not it was there before I installed the custom kernel.

Comment: Never compile android kernel, but don't you also need to enable support for config gz prior to compile the kernel? AFAIK it has to be enable in the normal kernel to be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check if you have "Enable access to .config through /proc/config.gz" (IKCONFIG_PROC) option enabled.

Comment: Where can I check that? Kernel conf?